# $\gamma(t)=(t^3,|t^3|) $ is $C^1$

Tags: limits, differential-geometry

This is easy, but sometimes I get confused by the notations, so to be sure

when we write $\underset{t\rightarrow 0}{lim} \:  \:   \frac{\gamma(t)-\gamma(0)}{t-0}$ what we mean is

$\underset{t\rightarrow 0}{lim} \: \frac{t^3}{t}$ and  $\underset{t\rightarrow 0}{lim} \: \frac{|t^3|}{t}$
and because both limits go to $0$ we can say $\gamma'(0)=(0,0)$
and the derivative of the curve would be

$\gamma'(t)=\begin{cases}
(3t^2,-3t^2) & \text{ if } t<0 \\ 
(3t^2,3t^2)& \text{ if } t\geq0  \\ 
\end{cases}$
and because it is continuous $\gamma$ is $C^1$

Comment: Yes, all correct.

Comment: Thank you for verifying